# Ouput escaping in my PHP (html tags render as it is)

Tags: php, xml, json, escaping

so I have text that is initially encoded as (an instance)

```
&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Location.&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt; &amp;lt;UL&amp;gt;&amp;lt;LI&amp;gt;Park Central New York Hotel is located in New York, N.Y.
```

This data is from an xml file. So before I process it , I convert it to a simplexmlelement object, json_encode it (with parameter 1) and then json_decode it. Ultimately what I have in my hand for the above is text rendered as which is what I am trying to render anyways.

```
<b>Location.</b><br /> <UL><LI>Park Central Ne
```

But the HTML tags do not render themselves, and simply output themselves as they are seen above. I am a little confused what function I need to apply here to get the desired output.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the page source show?

Comment: that's a good hint, should do so in the future next time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have double HTML-encoded your text. This string:

```
&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Location.&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;
```

will render as this when interpreted as HTML:

```
&lt;b&gt;Location.&lt;/b&gt;
```

You have to decode first using for example [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to get it to render as your desired output:

```
<b>Location.</b>
```

But better would be to fix the input so that it's not double encoded in the first place.

Comment: " I have double HTML encoded the text". -> does this refer to the operations I conduct on the data once I retrieve the information or does it indicate the opear